# How to get value in one row in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I have database table name emp_leave in postgreSQL9.3 like

| emp_name | department | ann_leave | med_leave | cas_leave | org_ann_lv | org_med_lv | org_cas_lv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tame | IT |  |  | 3 |  |  | 25 |
| Tame | IT | 4 |  |  | 20 |  |  |
| Tame | IT |  | 3 |  |  | 30 |  |

I want the query result like

| emp_name | department | ann_leave | med_leave | cas_leave | org_ann_lv | org_med_lv | org_cas_lv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tame | IT | 4 | 3 | 3 | 20 | 30 | 25 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want aggregation :

```
select el.emp_name, el.department, 
       max(el.ann_leave),
       . . . ,
       max(el.org_cas_lv)
from emp_leave el
group by el.emp_name, el.department;
```

This assumes blank space as `null`.

Answer (score 2):

To eliminate null value and convert into single row

```
select
emp_name,
department,
min(ann_leave),
min(med_leave),
min(cas_leave),
min(org_ann_lv),
min(org_med_lv),
min(org_cas_lv)
from emp_leave
group by
emp_name,
department
```