# group multiple rows with the same value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a certain result-set and I need to group them together on userId.

e.g.

```
userId  2019-01-15  2019-01-16
------------------------------
132     0           30_140
132     30_140      0
```

Required output:

```
userId  2019-01-15  2019-01-16
------------------------------
132     30_140      30_140
```

Since values contain non-numeric characters, SUM won't work.

Comment: Do you want to have `sum` of values in columns `2019-01-15` and `2019-01-16`

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed those columns are dynamic, but yes.
I was using SUM earlier before I had to concatenate two values.

Comment: @Nick, well with your answer to the previous post, I came to this point.

Comment: Visit <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539959/how-to-get-value-in-one-row-in-postgresql> to get the same question and answer.

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539959/how-to-get-value-in-one-row-in-postgresql> same question and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the empty values are all `0` or `NULL` you can just use `MAX`:

```
SELECT userID, MAX(`2019-01-15`) AS `2019-01-15`, MAX(`2019-01-16`) AS `2019-01-16`
FROM test
GROUP BY userID
```

Output:

```
userID  2019-01-15  2019-01-16
132     30_140      30_140
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=91168256e2121e6247041aaa9b6ed323)